# How to periodically refresh QGIS display with updated shapefiles?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins

I'm creating updated shapefiles for a fixed set of layers in a project every 15 mins. If the user has that project open in QGIS on a Windows 7 PC, I can't overwrite those shapefiles, so I rename the parent directory and recreate it with the new files. But the QGIS app is still looking at the old shapefiles. A manual refresh works fine, but we want the display to update automatically without user intervention.

Tried writing a plug-in to refresh the display every few minutes, but the display doesn't update until the plug-in completes. Also tried converting the plug-in to a stand-alone app, but seemed to have the same behavior. Someone else tried it on a Mac and it seemed to work a little better, but still had issues.

Now considering a hack to call a refresh app from a Windows task - are we missing something?

Using QGIS 1.7.4 originally, also tried QGIS 2.4 but no improvement.

Comment: did you try layer.setCacheImage( None ) + layer.triggerRepaint() ?